# Why does my player go through objects only when moving forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player that jumps forward. I also have trees on the roads. When the player tries to move backwards or sideways into a tree, I can't. However, when I move forward I go right through the object and move sideways. I check for collisions with coins and cars which both work it is just with the the trees that I go through sideways.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {

else if (col.gameObject.name == "tree1(Clone)" || col.gameObject.name == "tree2(Clone)" ||
               col.gameObject.name == "tree3(Clone)" || col.gameObject.name == "tree4(Clone)") {
        charController.canMove = false;
        if (gameObject.name == "LeftCollider" && charController.lastJump == JumpDirection.left) { // left collider
            charController.endPosition.z -= CharController.jumpDistance;
        } else if (gameObject.name == "RightCollider" && charController.lastJump == JumpDirection.right) { // right collider
            charController.endPosition.z += CharController.jumpDistance;
        } else if (gameObject.name == "FrontCollider" && charController.lastJump == JumpDirection.up) { // front collider
            charController.endPosition.x -= CharController.jumpDistance;
            environmentMaker.collideFront = true;
            environmentMaker.charRoadPos--;
        } else if (gameObject.name == "BackCollider" && charController.lastJump == JumpDirection.down) { // back collider
            charController.endPosition.x += CharController.jumpDistance;
        }
```

The Front/Left/Right/Back/Collider are just objects that are in front of my player.

Comment: It is also worth noting that rather than specifying every possible object you don't want to allow movement through you could just check the tag of the object. If you create a tag called "Trees" it would just be one check. if(col.gameobject.tag == "Trees") {charController.canMove = false;}

Answer (score 3):

If you want that your object don't pass from other object then, you should use colldier without [**isTrigger**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) check (isTrigger should be false) and use [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) Event instead OnTriggerEnter.

Answer (score 0):

you just using `Bounds` insteads of making many collider.